# How to see Large Memory Objects on my .Net Framework (not Core) application IN RUNTIME

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to look for large memory objects on my application in runtime. It's an website in asp.net running on a shared IIS server.

I want it to fix eventual memory leaks on my website. I can see the total memory my website is taking with System.GC.GetTotalMemory(). But without knowing what variable/object is taking all the memory, I cannot fix my code.

These are my restrictions:

- I cannot install any software on the server
- I cannot run my website on the server under the Visual Studio debbug
- I dont have permission to access the "Windows (Remote) Desktop"
- I need to do this inspection totally on my application code

At the moment, I have this support class on my website:

```
Class MemoryInspector

    Public Shared Function GetMemoryUsed() As Long
        Return System.GC.GetTotalMemory(False)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Collect()
        Return System.GC.Collect()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetLargeObjects() As List(Of Object)
        '.... I dont know how to code this function
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: No luck you can't use tooling to analyze your application. [Some are great](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/dotnet-alloc-tool?view=vs-2019).
Maybe use [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/weg/instrumenting-your-code-with-etw) so that you can request traces you can analyze offline.
This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) seems valuable too.
Take a look at [CLR MD](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd) which is a process and crash dump introspection library provided by Microsoft.

Comment: run a profiler in your browser, start it, do your executions, stop it. It will create a report and he heavy object will stand out.

Comment: Don't you have a separate server you can deploy the application to that is under fewer restrictions, and then you can use other tooling to inspect the memory?

Comment: I have another server. But for the memory to happen, I need the real userbase on the real online website. And there is a small chance to the error to happen. This is why I need to catch it on the online scenario.

Comment: You could use load testing software to simulate a real userbase.

Comment: Why wait for the error to happen to see the problem.  You should be able to see indicators of this loading even when debugging via VS.  If you are getting errors, your error handling & reporting should have enough info for you to track the problem.  You're probably building yourself a world of hurt, including profiling tools to be used in production bring their own complications

Comment: As you can see on my question, I'm looking for a solution via code and at runtime. Debug, simulations, and etc. are not an option. But I really appreciate your suggestions.